# change the first day of the week with work week view

Tags: momentjs, react-big-calendar

I'm trying to change the first day of the work_week view with react big calendar but I didn't found a way to do it... I was able to change the first day of the week view but nothing helped with work week... any ideas?

This is how I changed the first day of the week view:

```
import "moment/locale/en-gb";

moment.locale("en-gb", {
  week: {
    dow: 0,
  },
});

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to do this is by defining a custom 'View', rather than using the 'work_week' view. First you can create the 'View', using the 'work_week' view as a template.

```js
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";

import Week from "react-big-calendar/lib/Week";
import TimeGrid from "react-big-calendar/lib/TimeGrid";

function workWeekRange(date, options) {
  return Week.range(date, options).filter(
    (d) => [0, 1, 6].indexOf(d.getDay()) === -1
  );
}

class MyWorkWeek extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let { date, ...props } = this.props;
    let range = workWeekRange(date, this.props);

    return <TimeGrid {...props} range={range} eventOffset={15} />;
  }
}

MyWorkWeek.propTypes = {
  date: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date).isRequired
};

MyWorkWeek.defaultProps = TimeGrid.defaultProps;

MyWorkWeek.range = workWeekRange;

MyWorkWeek.navigate = Week.navigate;

MyWorkWeek.title = (date, { localizer }) => {
  let [start, ...rest] = workWeekRange(date, { localizer });

  return localizer.format({ start, end: rest.pop() }, "dayRangeHeaderFormat");
};

export default MyWorkWeek;
```

The magic there is in the `workWeekRange` method, where I defined the days (zero index) to hide from the week. In this example I'm hiding Sunday, Monday and Saturday.

Also notice that I had to change my import statements for the `Week` and `TimeGrid` components.

The last thing I had to do was provide the custom 'View', as well as a title for the button in the Toolbar. You do this in your calendar props. The `views` prop changes from the standard array to an object.

```js
  return (
    <Calendar
      // other props
      views={{
        day: true,
        month: true,
        myweek: MyWorkWeek
      }}
      messages={{
        myweek: 'Work Week'
      }}
    />
```

You can see a [working example in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z2jqpmlr14?file=/src/MyWorkWeek.component.js:0-945).

Comment: Thanks! this help me to include weekends in calendar with work week type. <3