# React big calendar custom view w/ Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-big-calendar

I am having troubles creating a [custom view](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/blob/master/examples/demos/customView.js) with the typed big calendar, each time I use a calendar component such as Timegrid or any other in my custom Week component as in the example, I get a standard error such as `react_devtools_backend.js:2560 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

If I use standard HTML or non big calendar components, the custom week works though.

```
import {NavigateAction, TimeGrid} from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment = require('moment')

interface MyWeekProps {
  date: Date
}

export class MyWeek extends React.Component<MyWeekProps> {
  static title = (date: Date) => {
    return `My awesome week: ${date.toLocaleDateString()}`
  }

  static navigate = (date: Date, action: NavigateAction) => {
    switch (action) {
      case 'PREV':
        return moment(date).add(-3, 'day').toDate()

      case 'NEXT':
        return moment(date).add(3, 'day').toDate()

      default:
        return date
    }
  }

  static range = (date: Date) => {
    let start = date
    let end = moment(start).add(2, 'day')

    let current = start
    let range = []

    while (moment(current).isSameOrBefore(moment(end), 'day')) {
      range.push(current)
      current = moment(current).add(1, 'day').toDate()
    }

    return range
  }

  render() {
    let {date} = this.props
    let range = MyWeek.range(date)

    return <TimeGrid range={range} eventOffset={15}/>
//return <div>{date}<div/> no error
  }
}
```

then used as

```
import {MyWeek} from 'reparator/rendezVous/rendezVousCustomWeek'

...

return <Calendar
    culture={culture}
    localizer={localizer}
    views={{month: true, week: MyWeek, day: true, agenda: true}}
    style={{height: props.fullScreen ? '800px' : '500px', width: '100%'}}
    messages={messages}
    startAccessor="start"
    endAccessor="end"
    min={minimum}
    max={maximum}
    timeslots={timeslots}
    step={step}
    events={props.rendezVous.map((rdv: RendezVous) => toEvent(rdv))}
    onSelectEvent={(event: EventRendezVous) => {
      if (!props.readOnly) {
        window.location.href = `#rendezVous/${event.id}/edition`
      }
    }}
    dayPropGetter={customDayPropGetter}
    slotPropGetter={customSlotPropGetter}
    eventPropGetter={customEventPropGetter}
    components={{
      event: customEvent,
      agenda: {
        event: customEventAgenda,
      },
    }}
  />
```

Comment: `import TimeGrid from 'react-big-calendar/lib/TimeGrid'`  Looking at the example you showed, TimeGrid is not part of the root `react-big-calendar`..

Comment: yes but the typed version of big calendar has those interfaces.
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f7ec78508c6797e42f87a4390735bc2c650a1bfd/types/react-big-calendar/index.d.ts
https://ibb.co/vwK2LC0

Comment: Yeah, they could be wrong, looking at the source code there not exporting it from the root.

Comment: thanks, not sure I have access to that import TimeGrid from 'react-big-calendar/lib/TimeGrid' though gonna try

Comment: You can follow this link. Here is the answer for custom week view https://stackoverflow.com/a/63970876/12489946

Answer (score 2):

so as [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870228/keith) suggested, the typescript version has export issues and importing the untyped complete module solves the problem :

```
// @ts-ignore
import * as TimeGrid from 'react-big-calendar/lib/TimeGrid'
```

<TimeGrid {...this.props} range={range} eventOffset={15}/>

and use this